# Comparing similar words in two different columns

Tags: excel, join, match, formula, vlookup

I have list of different categories in same dataset in two different columns.

Example data how the comparison should be:

[image]

There are some similar words in the two columns. So by comparing the two columns the maximum matched wordings should be created in new column as shown in attached image. Is their any formula that we can compare two columns.

I tried to use `vlookup` the cases but in that only full matched columns are joining. I need matching words to join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBA solution kind of works I guess but is definitely not 100% reliable:

```vb
Sub matchWords()
    Dim arr() As Variant, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = 3
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    arr = rng
    
    
    Dim val1 As String, val2 As String
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 3) = ""
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            val1 = LCase(arr(i, 2))
            If val1 <> "" Then val1 = Split(val1, ".")(UBound(Split(val1, ".")))
            val2 = LCase(Left(Replace(arr(j, 1), " ", ""), Int(Len(Replace(arr(j, 1), " ", "")) * 0.7)))
            If InStr(1, val1, val2) <> 0 Then
                arr(i, 3) = arr(j, 1) & "?" & arr(i, 3)
            End If
        Next j
        If val1 <> "" And arr(i, 3) <> "" Then arr(i, 3) = Left(arr(i, 3), Len(arr(i, 3)) - 1)
    Next i
    rng = arr
End Sub
```

Tested on this table called "data". Sometimes, there is more than one match in which case both of them are put into the third column, separated by a question mark:

| `cat1` | `cat2` | `matchedCat1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `anesthesiologist` | `professional. Accountants` | `accounting` |
| `appliances` | `nightlife.adultentertainment` | `adult entertainment` |
| `aircraft dealer` | `professional.advertising` | `advertising` |
| `airline` | `industry.agriculture` | `agriculture` |
| `animal shelter` | `auto.aircraftdealers` | `aircraft dealer` |
| `apartments` | `hotelstravel.transport.airlines` | `airline` |
| `airport` | `hotelstravel.airports` | `airport` |
| `alternative medicine` | `hotelstravel.airports.airportterminals` | `airport terminal?airport` |
| `amusement park` | `health.physicians.allergist` | `allergist` |
| `airport terminal` | `health.alternativemedicine` | `alternative medicine` |
| `allergist` | `active.amusementparks` | `amusement park` |
| `accounting` | `health.physicians.anesthesiologists` | `anesthesiologist` |
| `advertising` | `pets.animalshelters` | `animal shelter` |
| `agriculture` | `realestate.apartments` | `apartments` |
| `adult entertainment` | `shopping.homeandgarden.appliances` | `appliances` |

*just in case any moderator comes across this: The reason the table looks like this is because SO will not allow me to post it without each of the entries formatted as code. This "feature" seriously needs to either be fixed or done away with completely.

Comment: could you please show me the step wise procedure how i can use the vba script because i am new to this

Comment: @BrunoB I'm sure you can find a tutorial for that.

Comment: Run time error 1004-Method ‘Range’ of object’_Global’ failed” while executing an Excel macro

Comment: i got the tutorial but evry thing shows the process but didnt explain about the data, columns to add, how to add data, solution for error types

Comment: @BrunoB is it crashing on the set rng = Range("data") line? You probably don't have a range called data in your workbook... You have to modify that line to whatever your actual data is. Something like Range("A2:C15") would be appropriate for your example. Obviously if your data is larger, which I assume it is, you'll have to set the range to whatever size your actual data is. Tomorrow I'll try to rewrite the code so that it hopefully finds the range automatically.

Comment: i changed the range as suggested and run the script but it shows the error: subscript out of range

Comment: im using ms office 2019

Comment: @BrunoB I changed the code a little, you can try it out as it is now.

Comment: Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

Comment: @BrunoB on which line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252013/discussion-between-bruno-b-and-andrewb).